# How to pass Image uri from one screen to other, in React Native, using Expo Image Picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, file-upload, expo

I want to pass Image uri to the next screen, so I can select image on one Screen and display on other, is there any possible way around? I am Selecting Image from **Info.js** and want to show that selected image in **Profile.js**.
I am using React Native Version 0.64.3, and have built on Expo, in Linux. Expo Image Picker Version is 12.0.1
My Code is as below;

**Info.js**

```
export default function Info({ route, navigation }) {
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
    const [profilePicture, setprofilePicture] = useState('');

    const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [1, 1],
            quality: 1,
        });

        if (!result.cancelled) {
            setprofilePicture(result.uri);
            setModalVisible(false);
        }
    }
    const openCamera = async () => {
        const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [1, 1],
            quality: 1,
        });
        if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
            alert("You've refused to allow this appp to access your camera!");
            return;
        }
        const result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();
        // console.log(result);
        if (!result.cancelled) {
            setprofilePicture(result.uri);
            setModalVisible(false);
        }
    }
    
    if (profilePicture != '') {
        nextbtn = <NextBtn txt={"Next"} onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Profile', { profile: profilePicture }) }} />
    } else {
        nextbtn = <Text></Text>
    }
    var bg = ''
    if (profilePicture != '') {
        bg = { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }
    }

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={[s.surface, s.fullView, {paddingTop: 64}]}>
                {nextbtn}
                <Text style={[s.heading2, s.onSurface, s.container]}>Your Info</Text>
                <Text style={[s.txt, s.onSurface, s.containerLg, s.mt1, s.lhNormal, s.textCenter]}>Enter your name and add a profile picture.</Text>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={{ uri: profilePicture }}
                    resizeMode="cover"
                    style={{ marginTop: 18 }}
                    imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 100 }}
                >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        style={[s.profileSelector, bg]}
                        onPress={() => { setModalVisible(true) }}
                    >
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCamera} size={20} color={color.onSurfaceColor} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
            <Modal
                animationType="fade"
                transparent={true}
                visible={modalVisible}
                statusBarTranslucent={true}
                onRequestClose={() => {
                    Alert.alert('Modal has been closed.');
                    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                }}
            >
                <View style={[s.centeredView, s.bgOverlay]}>
                    <View style={s.modalView}>
                        <Text style={s.modalText}>Choose Info Picture</Text>
                        <View style={[s.dFlex, {flexDirection: 'row'}]}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                style={[s.profieSelection]}
                                onPress={openCamera}
                            >
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCamera} size={20} color={color.onSecondaryColor} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                style={[s.profieSelection]}
                                onPress={pickImage}
                            >
                                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faImages} size={20} color={color.onSecondaryColor} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        <Pressable
                            style={[s.btn, { minWidth: 260 }]}
                            onPress={() => setModalVisible(!modalVisible)}
                        >
                            <Text style={[s.btnText]}>Cancel</Text>
                        </Pressable>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View >
    )

}
```

**Profile.js**

```
export default function Profile({ route, navigation }) {
    const { profile } = route.params;
    var profilePicture = JSON.stringify(profile);
    console.log(profilePicture)
eturn (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={[s.surface, s.fullView, { paddingTop: 64 }]}>
                <Text style={[s.heading2, s.onSurface, s.container]}>Your Profile</Text>
                <Text style={[s.txt, s.onSurface, s.containerLg, s.mt1, s.mb2, s.lhNormal, s.textCenter]}>Enter your name and add a profile picture.</Text>
                <Image source={profilePicture} style={{ width: 136, borderRadius: 100, height: 136, backgroundColor: '#fff' }} />
            </View>
        </View >
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I was actually using Json.Stringify, which icludes "" (quotes), in string, which were causing issue, You can either remove ", or you can skip stringify at all.
i.e.

```
export default function Profile({ route, navigation }) {
    const { profile } = route.params;
eturn (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={[s.surface, s.fullView, { paddingTop: 64 }]}>
                <Text style={[s.heading2, s.onSurface, s.container]}>Your Profile</Text>
                <Text style={[s.txt, s.onSurface, s.containerLg, s.mt1, s.mb2, s.lhNormal, s.textCenter]}>Enter your name and add a profile picture.</Text>
                <Image source={profile} style={{ width: 136, borderRadius: 100, height: 136, backgroundColor: '#fff' }} />
            </View>
        </View >
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your using React Navigation, [heres](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/) the official guide on how to pass parameters to routes using react navigation

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `uri` of the image from one screen and pass it through navigation params to other screen.
Check out `@react-navigation/native`

```
const navigation = useNavigation();

const onPickImage = () => {
   // expo image picker codes here 

   navigation.navigate('SecondScreen', { uri });
}
```